noscript Twitter alternative without requiring javascript (JavaScript-free Mastodon)
Are there federated twitter alternatives that don't require javascript?
One of the main reasons I migrated from twitter (now X) was because the content became authwalled. I don't see much of a benefit of publishing content about my org to a social media platform when the content can't be viewed by the majority of the world.
I've been using Masotodon. While Mastodon doesn't have an authwall, it still has a JS wall. Limiting exposure of my org's posts on social media is the antithesis of why I use social media. The less walls to our content, the better.








Mastodon's JavaScript wall



It's very important to me that my org's social media feeds can be viewed by everyone, including security-conscious users that [a] don't register for an account, [b] don't want to download special software, and [c] use hardened browsers (eg Tor Browser) with javascript disabled.
Here's my requirements for the software:

100% FOSS (ideally AGPL)
Supports federation through ActivityPub (so interaction with Mastodon works flawlessly)
No mandatory authwall (Accounts can be exposed publicly, without requiring login to view their posts)
No special software (Website fully functional on vanilla Firefox and Chromium)
Noscript fallback (using javascript for Progressive Enhancement is fine, but all functionality should fully function in Tor Browser on Strict settings)

Are there any FOSS, federated (ActivityPub-powered) Micro blogging platforms with actively-developed web UIs that don't require javascript?

See also Enable use of mastodon without javascript mastodon/mastodon/#6186

I think the most popular FOSS software with ActivityPub support is wordpress. You might want to look into seeing if you can get a mastodon-account-like page using a JavaScript-free WordPress theme

It appears that Hubzilla supports ActivityPub and does not require javascript. Here's an example account feed on a Hubzilla instance https://hubzilla.org/channel/adminsforum

It appears that WriteFreely supports ActivityPub and does not require javascript. Here's an example account feed on a WriteFreely instance https://write.as/matt/
